# How to create a CNN image classification model that can generate a Text file for our labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I have a CNN model which should recognize fonts of the different alphabets, I use this code to generate my test and train and validation sets.

```
# load and iterate training dataset
train_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(dir, class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)
# load and iterate validation dataset
val_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(dir, class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)
# load and iterate test dataset
test_it = datagen.flow_from_directory(dir, class_mode='binary', batch_size=64)
```

and this is how I fit my model

```
# fit model
model.fit(train_it, steps_per_epoch=8, validation_data=val_it, validation_steps=5, epochs= 10)
```

my model at the end should get the input and then load the trained model and generate the labels in the output as a .txt file. The text file should have 1000 lines and in each line, the label of each sample is written, for example, “A”, “B”, etc. I want to know how I can do that?

Comment: I believe first you need to load your trained model using some help from: https://machinelearningmastery.com/save-load-keras-deep-learning-models/

Comment: Also about writing your results to a file: https://realpython.com/read-write-files-python/